# Convert each line in a text file to JSON and post it to an api in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-requests

I have a use case where I need to generate a JSON for each line in text file and do a post request to an API. This is what the file looks like:

```
Member_ID,Login_ID,First_Name,Last_Name,Entity
ID1,Jim1,Jim,Kong,Entity1
ID2,OlilaJ,Olila,Jayavarman,Entity1
ID3,LisaKop,Lisa,Kopkingg,Entity1
ID4,KishoreP,Kishore,Pindhar,Entity1
ID5,Gobi123,Gobi,Nadar,Entity1
```

I am new to the API world, so I want to know how can I do a post call with just the Member_ID and Login_ID parameters. The output for each line being successfully posted to the api needs to be shown as a log.

Comment: What the POST should look like depends on what API you're using.  What API are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're in luck! Python makes this quite easy

```
import json
import requests

delim = "," # Just in case you switch to tsv or something

with open('file.csv', 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        line_list = line.split(delim)
        Member_ID = line_list[0]
        Login_ID = line_list[1]
        payload = { # Or enclose this in json.dumps()
            "Member_ID": Member_ID,
            "Login_ID": Login_ID
        }
        r = requests.post("your-target-url.com", data=payload)
```

What's happening here is that you are processing the lines, splitting them, and then passing them as the payload of an HTTP POST request. You may want to add logic to skip the header row, or add parameters to authenticate with your API, but this is an easy way to do what you are talking about.

Comment: But what if I want to do it line by line, since I am guessing that once the payload becomes too huge, APIs would not be able to handle it.

Comment: This is line by line. Python lets you treat files as sequences. In context of my example `for line in file` means "go line by line and do: foo" -- so `payload` is rewritten each time

Comment: first line of the csv file will be header, so to get the actual Member_id and Login_id  you should start your loop with `file[1:]`

Comment: Oh! I just missed seeing that correctly! Thank you so much! I will try this method out. Also, if I want to just print the logs out to a file for each line converted and then passed as a POST request, how would I do that?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by logs in this context but python has a standard library logger `logging` and requests `response`s have a `.history` that you can log. Writing your own text file is just `with open("myfile.txt", "w") as file: foo`

Comment: @ManasJani if the answer resolved the original question, please mark it answered.

Comment: Yes, I did accept the answer, thank you! I had one more question, regarding this, what can I use in python if the file size is huge, like more than a million records? Is there any multi-threading that can be done to make the process more efficient?

Comment: Sure, you can use `asyncio`, `aiohttp`, `multiprocessing`...there's plenty of options for you in the python standard library. And of course python has client libraries for practically any mapreduce program or service. I'm also a fan of `dask`, the parallel panda.